# Removing prefix for default language breaks all the link

Tags: uri, i18n-l10n

Since I built the site I always used language prefix "en" for my site. English is my default language.

The thing is our SEO Expert said that this is content duplication for Google and we might get Panda penlty. Thus I removed "en" for English and now all my links are broken.

Thus, is there any way to do following:

**http://www.xyz.com/en/**business-opportunities/zimbabwean-supplier-beverage-flavourings-calls-financiers

automatically redirect it to "**http://www.xyz.com/**business-opportunities/zimbabwean-supplier-beverage-flavourings-calls-financiers". So that I can save

Answer (score 0):

Google into htaccess rules if you have the apache module mod_rewrite on the apache server (if it's an apache server you're using), you can make redirections based on REGEX patterns, so there's a little work for you there....

Comment: Hi There, Raf I already tried that but didn't worked. It started giving me too many redirections. Would you be able to post the possible command ?